# Observable not updating when entering input field

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have the following typescript code:

```
///<reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
///<reference path="typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
///<reference path="typings/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />
///<reference path="typings/knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.d.ts" />

class Municipality {
    id: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    name: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(
            id: number,
            name: string) {

        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
    }
}

class SettingsViewModel {
    public municipality: KnockoutObservable<Municipality>;

    constructor() {
        this.municipality = ko.observable(new Municipality(0, ""));
    }

    editName = function (item) {
        $('#editValueDialog').modal('show');
    }

    submitUpdate = function () {
        var data = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.municipality());
        console.log(data);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var serverData = JSON.parse($("#serverJSON").val());
    console.log(serverData);
    vm.municipality(new Municipality(serverData.Id, serverData.Name));
});

var vm: SettingsViewModel;
vm = new SettingsViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

In my view, I'm trying to just have a simple input-field:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: vm.municipality().name()">
```

The value of name is visible in the input-field, but when changing it, and triggering the submitUpdate event, the value hasn't changed, nor does it change when I check the attribute in the console.

if I enter:

```
vm.municipality().name('test')
```

in the console the value changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix would be to use vm.municipality().name.valueHasMutated() but it kinda looks like the binding has gone wrong somwhere.. .Maybe put the input field within a with bindings context so you can make somthing like this:

```
<!-- ko with: vm.municipality -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">
<!-- /ko -->
```

Don't know if this code will work, sorry no TS compiler and I don't have the time to convert your code to vanilla JS.

Hope some of this helps

Comment: Actually seems like this works. I'm curious why? gonna make a couple of more checks.

Comment: it probably worked because bindings are hard :P maybe also try this: <input type="text" data-bind="value: vm.municipality().name">

Comment: I don't fully get it yet so I don't know if that works and no jsfiddle so I cant test (and too lazy to make)

Answer (score 1):

```
submitUpdate = function () {
    var data = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.municipality());
    console.log(data);
};
```

Use an arrow function here -- the `this` value here is likely wrong at runtime when `submitUpdate` is triggered:

```
submitUpdate = () => {
    var data = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.municipality());
    console.log(data);
};
```

Comment: As I can see this did unfortunately not change anything. I dont think it's the actual submiitUpdate-event that's wrong, since the value hasn't changed when I check the console either. Well, it could be wrong there also of course, but wrong somewhere else also.